# Singly Linked List Implementation Issue

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to write C based implementation of a singly linked list.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct sllist {
    int data;
    struct sllist *next;
};
void InsertInLinkedList(struct sllist *head, int data, int position);

int main()
{
    int x;
struct sllist *s=NULL;

InsertInLinkedList(s,5,1);
x=ListLength(s);
printf("%d\n",x);
return 0;
}


int ListLength(struct sllist *head)
{
    struct sllist *current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return count;
}
void InsertInLinkedList(struct sllist *head, int data, int position)
{
    int k = 1;
    struct sllist *p, *q, *newNode;
    newNode = (struct sllist *)malloc(sizeof(struct sllist));
    if (!newNode) {
        printf("Memory Error\n");
        return;
    }
    newNode->data = data;
    p = head;
    if (position == 1) {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        while ((p != NULL) && (k < position - 1)) {
            k++;
            q = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        if (p == NULL) {
            q->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;
        } else {
            q->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = p;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to add a node to the list and then verify the length. However, I get the output as 0 rather than 1. What mistake am I making?

Thanks

Comment: Just an fyi, anytime you do an insert in position 1, you will lose the entire linked list.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
if (position == 1) {
    newNode->next = NULL;
    head = newNode;
}
```

has no effect... since newNode remains detached, and head get lost.

The function to insert a node in a linked list should return the modified list, or accept a pointer to pointer. Like the following:

```
void InsertHead(struct sllist **list, struct sllist *new_node) {
  new_node->next = *list;
  *list = new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To further explain manu-fatto's comment that the "head get lost"- when you pass a pointer to a function, you are only passing a copy of a number.  Modifying the number inside the function only modifies the function's local copy.  It has no effect on the calling function's pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am having some more issues in understanding the implementation.When adding a node to the end of the list, it does q->next = newNode; Shouldn't it be p->next=newNode since p is the last node's next pointer?

Comment: There are two places where the code "q->next = newNode" happens... in the first case, p is NULL, so you definitely don't want to do p->anything.  In the second case, p is pointing to the node that comes after the inserted node.  The one just before it is what q is pointing to.